# What is the narrowest possible functioning straw that could be made?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, atoms, molecular-dynamics

Let's assume that the straw/pipe/tube can be made of any material, but it should be at least 100 times as long as the inside is wide.

How narrow could the inside of the straw be made before it is no longer possible to consistently move any substance through the straw from one end to the other? What would the "substance" be?

EDIT: It looks like I need to change the word “straw” to “tube” or something similar. There shouldn’t be any suction involved. The input force can be as energetic as required. I’m more interested in the substance that could be sent through the tube, and the point at which the straw/tube becomes so tiny that nothing can move through it?

Comment: I'll assume when you say 'straw' you are referring  to the fluid being under a standard atmosphere of pressure and the sucking end at some pressure lower than atmosphere. I'm not going to work the problem for you, but basically you draw a free body diagram. Consider that the sucking end can go no lower than a  vacuum (absolute zero pressure). At the fluid end you have the column pressure $\rho gh$ pulling against the vacuum, but you have to take into account the vapor pressure of the fluid that will reduce $h$. So far the cross sectional area didn't even need to be considered ...

Comment: ... so far like the barometer. But  one more force that does depend on the area, or rather the circumference of the liquid-solid contact, the surface tension which is specific between the solid and the liquid. Add all these forces up to create an equilibrium equation of forces. To be a 'functioning' straw  you need to have upward progress of the fluid, so the balance of forces has to be slightly off balance in the upper direction. You are asking for 'fluid' and straw 'diameter' so two unknowns. Pick minimum known fluid, its $\rho$ then solve for diameter.

Comment: @docscience, isn't there a similitude parameter for scaling systems where surface tension and viscosity are important? I can't remember what it's called...

Comment: @nielsnielsen   There is a dimensionless number, the capillary number that relates those parameters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_number . Is that it?

Comment: @docscience, yes that's it exactly, by using this one should be able to place bounds on when a straw stops being useful as a straw, based on the maximum amount of suction you could draw by mouth, plus viscosity and whatnot.